# How do you move an app from the internal sd card to the external sd card

Tags: external-sd, app2sd, internal-sd

Can someone answer my problem? I have a digital2 deluxe II tablet containing an internal storage of 1.97 gb and an internal sd card of 3.74 gb and it's kinda full and my problem is I have an external sd card of 32 gb and everytime I press move to sd card it moves the app to the internal and I can't move it to the external sd and it's kinda annoying can somebody help? Note: no rooting please

Comment: What Android version is running on your device? You might also wish to consult our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info).

Answer (score 2):

Moving applications to your *external SD card* is not possible anymore because Android has changed i's way of managing storage. Your *internal storage* is now your *SD card* and your external one is a different, second *SD card*.

If you'd like to move apps to your external *SD card* then you have to manually change your *external SD's* mount point and swap it with the internal one.
Of course this requires you to root your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to upgrade to Android >=6.0 or install a custom rom?

Since Android 6.0 is it possible to use the external SD card as internal storage. If you do so all data on it will be erased and the card will be repartitioned.
I' quite new to but I installed Resurrection Remix OS 3 weeks ago but running again into the storage limitation of my SII (I9100), I might used the wrong PIT (see *Increase system partition size* or *Lanchon REPIT* on xda).

Anyway as far as I understand, depending on your Android version, you can either use any of the apps such as AppMgr Pro III, Link2SD or App2SD what are able to partition and mount your extSD as internal storage, there is a tutorial on classroom.synonym.com (*How to Partition Your SD Card in a Droid for APP2SD*). May you have look on forums.androidcentral.com (*[TUTORIAL] Everything you wanted to know about app2sd, ext3, ext4 partitions!!*)

Using the >Android 6.0 in-build feature is a way more handy but that would imply that you install a custom rom but I couldn't find any for it, may you find one.

Regardless the outcome of this research, someone needs to answer the question how Android manage the internal *Data* and *Media* partition combined with the external partition before running again in any limitation and being able to utilise all 32 GB or 64 GB of the extSD. I found 2 well explained tutorials ([#1](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/109134/p/1449,9582) & [#2](http://gadgetguideonline.com/android/android-marshmallow-guide/how-to-use-micro-sd-card-as-internal-storage-in-android-marshmallow/)) but both missing this detail.

Answer (score -2):

Install Apps2SD from Play Store. Open the app. You will see the apps of your phone in 3 categories - In phone, In card and ROM. You can't move the app in the ROM category but you can move those in the Phone. Just long hold the app you want to move and from the option which pop-up, select Move to SD Card...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Poster is already using the App2SD functionality built into the OS, and apps are moving to the internal SD rather than the external SD.  This is due to the way the manufacturer sets up the device's internal storage (emulated SD card), which, in KitKat, blocks use of the external SD card for app storage.